# making call and receice data from gsm modem in C#

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command

i want to call a service number like that `*21*2#` with `AT Command` using gsm modem but also i want to receive the answer ( because it is a service number ) in `RichtextBox` , hox to do that ? :(

```js
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    SerialPort po = new SerialPort();  
    po.PortName = "COM3";  
    po.BaudRate = int.Parse( "9600");  
    po.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");  
    po.Parity = Parity.None;  
    po.StopBits = StopBits.One;  
    po.ReadTimeout = int.Parse("300");  
    po.WriteTimeout = int.Parse("300");  
    po.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");  
    po.Open();  
    po.DtrEnable = true;  
    po.RtsEnable = true;  
    po.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);  
    po.Write("ATD9030665834;");  
}  
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)  
    {  
              
    }  
}
```

Comment: I object to closing this question as too broad. It could perhaps be interpreted as two different questions, a) how to invoke a service number and get a response, and b) how to present that information in a text box. While just b) probably is too broad, a) most certainly is not - **it is a clearly defined and limited question**.

Comment: Maybe the question asker wonders about both, or perhaps the b) information is added just as a context information in how the response is going to be consumed. I'll give the asker the benefit of the doubt and assume that he/she will be able to figure out how to present it if having the response available in a string variable. I'll see if I get time to write an answer sometime during the weekend.